# Admin custom page form action not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, custom, forms, action

I have create custom page in `admin`. Here am trying to save the some data to database.

I have doubt in `form action` this my code

**.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("*/*/insertsilverrateAction") ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="rate" value="10.10" required="">
    <button type="submit" name="save" class="scalable save"><span><span><span>Submit</span></span></span></button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function insertsilverrateAction()
    {
        echo 'h1';
    }
}
```

When i click submit button redirect to `404-page`.

How can add correct `form action`

Comment: `<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("{routers-module}/createadmincontroller/insertsilverrateaction") ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form action to

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("your_adminhtml_router/custom/insertsilverrate") ?>
```

you can get your adminhtml router from `etc/config.xml` file

Comment: this my current form action url http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/index.php/admin/custom/insertsilverrate/key/55ff5e4be22f8fc478686eecd00bc7f2/

Comment: When i click submit button it redirect to dashboard page.

Comment: check my updated answer